# Submit photo to database from Image Gallery in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an images index page which displays an entire album of photos from the User's Facebook profile in a uniform square grid. To get the square grid shape, I had to use some css which crops a little bit of the image from the sides (essentially a thumbnail).

I want the users to be able to click on an image so that a modal comes up that shows the full image, which they can then crop themselves.

Most importantly, I'm wondering how to make it so the modal that pops up is like a form, where you select the part that you want cropped and then click submit, and the photo and crop parameters get saved to the database

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<% @profile = @graph.get_object("me") %>
<%= @profile["name"] %><br>
<%= link_to 'Sign Out', sign_out_path, method: :delete %>

<br>

<% @albums = @graph.get_connections("me", "albums?fields=name,photos{name, images{source}}") %>
<% @albums.at(3)["photos"]["data"].each do |data| %>
    <div id="<%= data["id"] %>" class="myImages" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <%= image_tag data["images"].first["source"] %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myImages").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".modal-body").html($(this).html());
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: A good starting point for this functionality is `j-crop` - http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html